# How can I determine the circuit from a transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, matlab, laplace-transform

I have identified a couple of transfer functions, which fit well to measured data, using MATLAB system identification toolbox.

How can I determine a circuit diagram from these transfer functions?

$$\frac{a_1\!\cdot\!s + a_0}{s^2 + b_1\!\cdot\!s + b_0}$$

and

$$\frac{a_1\!\cdot\!s + a_0}{b_1\!\cdot\!s + b_0}$$

Comment: It doesn't sound possible to me. I'll try to explain why over the first transfer function only: The first TF clearly shows that there could be two cascade-connected blocks, and presumably one of them is a second order system which can be a four-element (i.e. two R-C pairs) active or passive filter. Active filter is formed by an operational amplifier while the passive filter is formed by only passive elements. Active filter provides amplification while the passive one doesn't. By looking at the TF only it may not be possible to see if the amplification comes from the filter or the other block.

Comment: What do those t.f. represent? Is it a bi-directional t.f.? Is it a passive or active approach? What exactly are you trying to model? -- there may be different approaches, or already found solutions to your problem.

Comment: I am trying to find an electrical analogy to a physical (not electrical) system. It is for illustrative purposes.

Comment: What kind of "physical" system? Thermal?

Comment: Express the TF in controller canonical form. The two integrations and the numerator summing junction can then be realised using op amps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with transfer function (TF) as the ones you've shown, you need to rewrite them in a *low-entropy* form in which poles, zeroes and gain/attenuation are explicitly factored. A simple factorization in the numerator and the denominator will meet this format quickly, naturally shedding light on the what the TF does:

[image]

So for the first one, we see a dc gain followed by a zero and a double pole. Depending on the quality factor value, the expression can be rewritten in two cascaded poles easier to treat.

From that expression, you need to think of a possible network building this transfer function. For the first one, a second-order \$LC\$ network should do the work as long as a zero is added. Using the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs described in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371), I can quickly derive the TF of this network:

[image]

Then, and that is the most difficult part, you need to determine the components values based on the TF parameters. That is a system of equations you need to solve. I went the other (simpler) way already assigning arbitrary values to the filter and copying them to the starting *high-entropy* expression. As you can see, the results are identical:

[image]

You can repeat this flow for your second expression which hosts a dc gain, a pole and a zero. *Always* rewrite raw expressions in a factored form from which you can extract information immediately, that is the key for this kind of exercise.